# "php.ini" with wordpress, if exist all works well. I can not find a sense

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, php-ini

I have a problem that have no sense.

I'm using WordPress and when I'm logged in I see a different page. All works well, but one of my user, when logged in, sees the home page white. It 'strange because all other users and my administrator account have no problem.

If I create a **"php.ini"** file with **"error_reporting(0);"** and I put it on the root folder, it works. Also the home page before that was white.

What's going on? What is the most logical explanation?

Comment: impossible to answer with out code

Comment: That wouldn't be the correct syntax for a `php.ini` anyway. Look into the webservers error.log. Otherwise this isn't answerable.

Comment: please check once permission or assigned role for that specific user

Comment: This user have the same permission of all other users..